# Apply formatting and formulas to another sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a template tab that contains all formulas and formatting. Then one tab for each user. I know how to reference cell content with `=template!A1`. How to reference formula that reference current tab? And how to reference formatting?

[Link to my sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18EikieMi6mj9DDF1qjivphodRDdlf77PcGMal_lLLcU/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spreadsheet functions cannot access either formulas or formatting of other cells. (Script functions can, but that is another story).

It seems what you want to do is the *duplicate your template sheet*, so that new sheets will have the same formatting and formulas. There is an easy way to do this: "Duplicate" command in the context menu of the sheet.

[image: duplicate]

This copies all values, formulas, and formatting.

However, if you think that the values in column B may be changed in the future, then you don't want them to be just copied to other sheets: you want references. To achieve this,

1. Duplicate "template" once, the new copy could be "user sheet". Edit the cells in B column of "user sheet" so they reference the template: `=template!B5`, and so on.
2. After that, duplicate only "user sheet", not the template sheet. The duplicates will have the same references `=template!B5` in them. The "template" sheet could even be hidden, because you'll need it only on the occasion when the values need to be edited.

#### Aside on protection

Instead of telling users "only edit yellow cells", you can actually prevent them from editing other cells, by using sheet protection with exception of a given range:

[image: protect]

However, protection does not get copied by the Duplicate command, so you would need to either add it manually to every sheet, or use a [script for copying protections/permissions](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/87000).