# Sheets based on a template don't maintain protected status

Tags: google-sheets

I am having trouble with a Google Sheet Template. It is a simple form with some formulas. I have locked the whole sheet except for some cells that the user should be allowed to edit.

This document is saved as a Template and when a user creates a new document based on this template, the protected segments are not inherited. The user is able to edit everything.

Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: Related: [In Google Sheets how do I duplicate a sheet along with its permission](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/86984/354)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is the expected (but not necessarily the ideal) behaviour because the person who copies the template then becomes the 'owner' of the copy.  The owner then can access the protected cells.  The only real answer is to make the copies for them so that you remain as the owner and they are just editors.