# How to duplicate a Google Sheet template sheet dynamically, preserving the protected cells permissions

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, permissions

I have two Google Sheet script functions that both work independently: 1) duplicates a template sheet, populating each duplicate sheet from a separate row of data in a source range; 2) makes a single duplicate of the template sheet and preserves its editing permissions - it's a protected sheet with unprotected ranges (using [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/86984/in-google-sheets-how-do-i-duplicate-a-sheet-along-with-its-permission)). I am trying to combine the two so that each copy of the template using the source data has the same permissions as the template sheet. I cannot work out how to nest one function inside the other. The two script functions are:

1)

```
function createTeamSheets() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

// Get the range of cells that store the data.
  var teamDataRange = ss.getRangeByName("SheetName");
  var teamObjects = teamDataRange.getValues();

  var template = ss.getSheetByName('TemplateTeamSheet');

  for (var i=0; i < teamObjects.length; i++) {

    // Put the sheet you want to create in a variable
    var duplicate = ss.getSheetByName(teamObjects[i]);

    // Check if the sheet you want to create already exists. If so,
    // log this and loop back. If not, create the new sheet.

                if (duplicate) {
           Logger.log("Sheet " + teamObjects[i] + "already exists");
        } else {

          if (teamObjects[i] == '') {
           break;
        } else {
           template.copyTo(ss).setName(teamObjects[i]);
           }
        }
  }

  return;
}
```

and 2)

```
function duplicateProtectedSheet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  template = ss.getSheetByName("TemplateTeamSheet");
  duplicate = template.copyTo(ss).setName("My Copy");

  var p = template.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET)[0];
  var p2 = duplicate.protect();
  p2.setDescription(p.getDescription());
  p2.setWarningOnly(p.isWarningOnly());  
  if (!p.isWarningOnly()) {
    p2.removeEditors(p2.getEditors());
    p2.addEditors(p.getEditors());
    p2.setDomainEdit(p.canDomainEdit()); //  only if using an Apps domain 
  }
  var ranges = p.getUnprotectedRanges();
  var newRanges = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
    newRanges.push(duplicate.getRange(ranges[i].getA1Notation()));
  } 
  p2.setUnprotectedRanges(newRanges);

}
```

How do I use variables p and p2 from the second function in the first function so that each instance of *template.copyTo(ss).setName(teamObjects[i])* preserves the template sheet's permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out

```
function createTeamSheets() {
  var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

// Get the range of cells that store team data.
  var teamDataRange = ss.getRangeByName("SheetName");
  var teamObjects = teamDataRange.getValues();

  var template = ss.getSheetByName('TemplateTeamSheet');

  for (var i=0; i < teamObjects.length; i++) {

    // Put the sheet you want to create in a variable
    var duplicate = ss.getSheetByName(teamObjects[i]);

    // Check if the sheet you want to create already exists. If so,
    // log this and loop back. If not, create the new sheet.


        if (duplicate) {
           Logger.log("Sheet " + teamObjects[i] + "already exists");
        } else {

          if (teamObjects[i] == '') {
           break;
        } else {
           template.copyTo(ss).setName(teamObjects[i]).showSheet();


var duplicatesheet = ss.getSheetByName(teamObjects[i]);


var p = template.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET)[0];          
var p2 = duplicatesheet.protect();

  p2.setDescription(p.getDescription());
  p2.setWarningOnly(p.isWarningOnly());  
  if (!p.isWarningOnly()) {
    p2.removeEditors(p2.getEditors());
    p2.addEditors(p.getEditors());
    p2.setDomainEdit(p.canDomainEdit()); //  only if using an Apps domain 
  }
  var ranges = p.getUnprotectedRanges();
  var newRanges = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
    newRanges.push(duplicatesheet.getRange(ranges[i].getA1Notation()));
  } 
  p2.setUnprotectedRanges(newRanges);


        }
        }          
}  
return;
}
```