# Script to Duplicate Template Tab Multiple Times and Rename Tabs from Cell Range?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

Basically, I have a list of 200 people's names in the range `'Names'!A1:A200`. I have another tab named **Template**. I need a script to duplicate **Template** 200 times and rename each of the tabs to the name of each of the people in the range `'Names'!A1:A200`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
function onOpen() {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('My Menu')
        .addItem('Create New Tabs', 'createTabs')
        .addToUi()}

function createTabs() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
    ss.getSheetByName('Names').getRange('A:A').getValues().filter(String)
        .forEach(function (sn) {
            if (!ss.getSheetByName(sn[0])) {
                ss.insertSheet(sn[0], ss.getSheets().length);}})}
```

This script will create a new custom menu/submenu with the option to create new tabs/sheets. The usage is: create a new sheet and rename it to **Names** and then populate column **A** with desired names

```
Ema
Emily
etc.
```

and then go to **My Menu** and select **Create New Tabs**

[image]

and for template copy/duplication you may want to check:

- **https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/115857/186471**
- **http://googleappscripting.com/copy-sheets-from-template/#script**